# Android google analytics doesn't work

Tags: android, google-analytics

Here is my code snippet.I don't know why its not working. When I open application on my android (S3) phone. No information is displaying in real time view.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GoogleAnalyticsTracker analyticsTracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        analyticsTracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
        analyticsTracker.startNewSession("UA-XXXXXXX-X", 5, this);
        analyticsTracker.trackPageView("/HomeScreen");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ;
    }

    public void one(View view) {
        analyticsTracker.trackEvent("OneCategory", // Category
                "OneAction", // Action
                "One", // Label
                77); // Value
        analyticsTracker.trackPageView("/HomeScreen");
    }

    public void two(View view) {
        analyticsTracker.trackEvent("TwoCategory", // Category
                "TwoAction", // Action
                "Two", // Label
                77); // Value
        analyticsTracker.trackPageView("/HomeScreen");

    }

    public void three(View view) {
        analyticsTracker.trackEvent("ThreeCategory", // Category
                "ThreeAction", // Action
                "Three", // Label
                77); // Value
        analyticsTracker.trackPageView("/HomeScreen");

    }

    public void dispatch(View view) {
        analyticsTracker.dispatch();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        analyticsTracker.stopSession();
        super.onDestroy();

    }
```

Manifest also include required permissions.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: shouldn't you send() the Tracker after calling trackPageView()?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving a look to the logs while using the emulator. Might be helpful. Otherwise might give below solution a try.

I too had some problems with the instation of the GATracker. The latest library includes `EasyTracker` which saves you from the overhead.

-- Add `res/values/analytics.xml` file which contains the `analytics profile` config details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
   <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
   <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXX-Y</string>

   <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
   <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

   <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
   <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

-- Set context for `EasyTracker` in your activity using the following

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
```

-- Now you cane make a call to `EasyTracker`

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   ... // The rest of your onStart() code.
   EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method.
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ... // The rest of your onStop() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); // Add this method.
}
```

-- Other event calls can be made like,

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().sendEvent(String category, String action, String label, long value);
```

Hope this helps. A more detailed documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/?hl=en#intro)